# What does the @ mean in ls -l?

Tags: permissions, osx, ls

I am using Mac OSX. When I type `ls -l` I see something like

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 xonic  staff    408 22 Jun 19:00 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 xonic  staff    306 22 Jun 19:42 ..
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 xonic  staff   6148 25 Mai 23:04 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--@  1 xonic  staff  17284 22 Jun 00:20 filmStrip.cpp
-rw-r--r--@  1 xonic  staff   3843 21 Jun 21:20 filmStrip.h
```

What do the @'s mean?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

It indicates the file has [extended attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes). You can use the `xattr` command-line utility to view and modify them:

```
xattr -l file # lists the names of all xattrs.
xattr -w attr_name attr_value file # sets xattr attr_name to attr_value.
xattr -d attr_name file # deletes xattr attr_name.
xattr -c file # deletes all xattrs.
xattr -h # prints help
```

Comment: In 10.8 (Mountain Lion), --list is not valid. It's -l.

Comment: if you want to find all files of a type and remove the quarantine attr in OSX: `find . -iname '*.ext' -print0 | xargs -0 xattr -d com.apple.quarantine`. That's why I found this question.

Comment: also, for SEO: @ is the "at symbol"

Comment: Didn't work for me. Had to use xattr -d instead of --delete.

Comment: @jcollum better yet, `find . -type f -xattr -print | xargs -0 xattr -d com.apple.quarantine` (not sure if the `-type f` is needed). Although for some reason neither command is working for me at the moment... This one worked for me: `find . -type f -xattr -exec xattr -d com.apple.quarantine {} \;`

Answer (score 42):

In Snow Leopard, at least, you can do this to show more information:

```
ls -l@
```

Comment: Right from the `xattr` manual:
`Attribute names can also be displayed using ``ls -l@''.`

Answer (score 3):

It has extended attributes - See the OSX man page [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) for more information on ls.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.  It redirects to the MacOS homepage.

Answer (score 2):

I think it means that the file/directory has [extended attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [this post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macos-x-server/2008/Jan/msg00138.html) in the Apple mailing lists. It explains that the @ shows that the Finder has extended attributes other than ACL.

Answer (score 0):

On OSX, this indicates the presence of metadata associated with the file.

Comment: It doesn't mean symbolic link on Linux either--symbolic links are denoted by an l in the first column of permissions, or broken links by a @ at the end of the path, not at the end of the permissions string.

Comment: Got it, edited.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to 
Michael Mrozek's answer:

On OSX 10.10 (Yosemite) you can have to use these attrx parameters:

```
xattr -l file
xattr -w attr_name attr_value file
xattr -d attr_name file
```