# + or @ mark after running 'ls -al'

Tags: osx, ls

In Mac OS X, run 'ls -al' gives me something like this.

```
drwxrwxrwx+  4 smcho  staff     136 May  5 09:18 Public
drwxr-xr-x+  6 smcho  staff     204 Feb  1  2010 Sites
drwxrwxrwx   9 smcho  staff     306 Feb  2  2010 backup
drwxr-xr-x@ 36 smcho  staff    1224 Sep  4 22:51 bin
```

- What's the + or @ at the end of the first column means?
- Is this unique to Mac, or common in UNIX?

### ADDED

After Michael Mrozek's answer, I ran 'ls -ale' to get the following.

```
drwx------+ 66 smcho  staff    2244 Aug 30 13:40 Library
 0: group:com.apple.sharepoint.group.3 allow search
 1: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   3 smcho  staff     102 Sep  4 15:01 Mail
drwx------+ 13 smcho  staff     442 Aug 28 17:55 Movies
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  6 smcho  staff     204 Jul  9 09:37 Music
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 11 smcho  staff     374 Aug 28 16:55 Pictures
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   3 smcho  staff     102 Mar 18 15:43 Projects
drwxrwxrwx+  4 smcho  staff     136 May  5 09:18 Public
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+  6 smcho  staff     204 Feb  1  2010 Sites
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

What those appended messages mean? Why do I have them for some of the files? I don't remember doing anything particular for them.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `@` suffix is unique to Mac OS and is covered by [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10/73), so I copied this part of my answer from there; it means the file has [extended attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes). You can use the `xattr` command-line utility to view and modify them:

```
xattr --list filename
xattr --set propname propvalue filename
xattr --delete propname filename
```

---

The `+` suffix means the file has an access control list, and is common in any *nix that supports ACLs. Giving `ls` the `-e` flag will make it show the associated ACLs after the file, and `chmod` can be used to modify then. Most of this is from the `chmod` man page:

You add an ACL with `chmod +a "type:name flag permission,..."`, and remove it with `chmod -a`. The argument to `chmod` is fairly complicated:

- **type** is either `user` or `group`, to clarify if `name` is referring to a username or a group name. If `name` is unambiguous, you can omit the type
- **name** is the username or group the ACL applies to
- **flag** is `allow` if this ACL entry is granting a permission, or `deny` if it's denying a permission
- **permission** is the actual permission being modified; you can list as many as you like, comma-separated

  - **delete** -- Allow the file/directory to be deleted
  - **readattr** -- Read basic attributes
  - **writeattr** -- Write basic attributes
  - **readextattr** -- Read extended attributes (using `xattr`, from above)
  - **writeextattr** -- Write extended attributes
  - **readsecurity** -- Read ACL info
  - **writesecurity** -- Write ACL info
  - **chown** -- Change owner
  - Directory-specific permissions

    - **list** -- Show the files/folders in the directory
    - **search** -- Find a file/folder in the directory by name
    - **add_file** -- Create a new file in the directory
    - **add_subdirectory** -- Create a new directory in the directory
    - **delete_child** -- Remove a file/directory in the directory
    - Inheritance-control

      - **file_inherit** -- ACLs on the directory are inherited by files
      - **directory_inherit** -- ACLs on the directory are inherited by subdirectories
      - **limit_inherit** -- Stops ACLs inherited by this directory from being inherited by subdirectories
      - **only_inherit** -- Inherited by all newly created items but ignored
  - File-specific permissions

    - **read** -- Open the file for reading
    - **write** -- Open the file for writing
    - **append** -- Open the file for appending
    - **execute** -- Run the file

In your particular example, most of the ACL entries are `group:everyone deny delete`. That is, all users in the `everyone` group (which is naturally everyone) are denied the permission to delete the folder. I believe, although I can't find any documentation about it, that these are default ACLs to stop you from removing essential root folders -- somebody correct this if that's not the case. The only other entry is `group:com.apple.sharepoint.group.3 allow search`, which allows Directory Services to search for files by name in the `/Library` folder

Comment: Showing `+` to indicate an ACL that goes beyond the traditional unix bits is common (at least FreeBSD, Linux and Solaris also do it; I don't know who did it first).

Comment: Mac OS also puts ACLs on key directories in the home directory. For example, Pictures has group:everyone deny delete. This actually makes it very difficult for the user to delete these directories, even if he doesn't want them.

Comment: The args must have changed over the years.  I found working answers/fixes at http://backdrift.org/fixing-mac-osx-file-permissions-and-acls-from-the-command-line

Comment: Thanks for the xattr command. I use `xattr -c filename` to clear all attrs so that the file can be accessed now.

Comment: Now for the Mac `xattr` does not support double minus arguments. Use `xattr -h` for more info.