# What does the at sign `@` and `+` sign mean when doing `ls -l`

Tags: bash, ls, macos

This is on macOS Mojave.  I tried to get the size of directories by using

```
du -csh */
```

in my home directory.  But the directory `Library` was giving `Operation not permitted`.  So I used `sudo` to do it, and it was the same thing.

Then I did

```
ls -l Library
```

and saw

```
drwx------+  35 peter  staff   1120 Mar 11 10:12 Logs/
drwx------@   3 peter  staff     96 Mar 18  2014 Mail/
```

What does the `@` and `+` mean?  The `Logs` actually allowed access but not `Mail.`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/or-mark-after-running-ls-al

Answer (score 7):

This is described [in the `ls` manual](https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html) on macOS:

> The Long Format If the -l option is given, the following information
>   is displayed for each file: file mode, number of links, owner name,
>   group name, number of bytes in the file, abbreviated month,
>   day-of-month file was last modified, hour file last modified, minute
>   file last modified, and the pathname. In addition, for each directory
>   whose contents are displayed, the total number of 512-byte blocks used
>   by the files in the directory is displayed on a line by itself,
>   immediately before the information for the files in the directory. **If
>   the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field
>   printed by the -l option is followed by an @ character. Otherwise, if
>   the file or directory has extended security information, the
>   permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a +
>   character**.