# What does @ sign mean in 'ls' output on Mac OSX Lion terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, osx, ls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does the @ mean in ls -l?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l)

What does the @ sign mean in the following "ls" output?

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root wheel 489 Jan 4 13:14 boot.plist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the @ indicates an extended permissions set.  The -e option will display the extended attributes.