# What do the symbols displayed by ls -F mean?

Tags: ls

I noticed that if I run ls -F on a directory, some of the entries have a * or a @ after them.

```
spuder@ubuntu:~$ ls -F /sbin
acpi_available*   getpcaps*           lvmconf*                 ntfscp*        start-stop-daemon*
agetty*           getty*              lvmdiskscan@             ntfslabel*     status@
alsa*             halt@               lvmdump*                 ntfsresize*    stop@
alsactl*          hdparm*             lvmsadc@    

spuder@ubuntu:~$ ls -F ~
daq-0.6.1/  examples.desktop       noname-cache.lib  snort-2.9.1/   Templates/
Desktop/    jpgraph-1.27.1/        noname.sch        snortfiles/    Ubuntu One/
Documents/
```

According to the ls man pages

```
spuder@ubuntu:~$ man ls
...
-F, --classify
  append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
...
```

I'm guessing that `@` means symbolic link,

What do these other indicators mean ( `*/=>@|` )  ?

Comment: See also: [Ask Ubuntu: What do the symbols like =, * and | in the output of "ls -F" mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82357/what-do-the-symbols-displayed-by-ls-f-mean)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`ls -F` appends symbols to filenames. These symbols show useful information about files.

- `@` means [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (or that the file [has extended attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l)).
- `*` means [executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions).
- `=` means [socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html).
- `|` means [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).
- `>` means [door](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_(computing)).
- `/` means [directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_directory).

If you want this behavior to be the default, add this to your shell configuration: `alias ls='ls -F'`.

Comment: do not realias commands, it can break badly written scripts. I have aliased `l` to have -F and colour, and `ll` to also have -l

Comment: Where is the "official Unix/Linux" list of these indicator entries types?

Comment: @ManuelJordan, see another answer (in short: `info ls`)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'd agree with you except that many shells are distributed with aliases in-box for many commands anyway, including `ls`, e.g. MINGW64/Git-Bash-for-Windows has `alias ls='ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars'`. I'm of the opinion that badly written scripts should be corrected instead of ultimately compromising our UX and QoL to accommodate those scripts.

Comment: My comment relates to the attached answer, not to default configurations.

Answer (score 9):

Just to add how I found this info. As indicated at the bottom of `man ls`:

> Full documentation at: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/ls
> or available locally via: info '(coreutils) ls invocation'

Following this, we see

> ‘-F’ ‘--classify’ ‘--indicator-style=classify’ Append a character to
> each file name indicating the file type. Also, for regular files that
> are executable, append ‘*’. The file type indicators are ‘/’ for
> directories, ‘@’ for symbolic links, ‘|’ for FIFOs, ‘=’ for sockets,
> ‘>’ for doors, and nothing for regular files. Do not follow symbolic
> links listed on the command line unless the --dereference-command-line
> (-H), --dereference (-L), or --dereference-command-line-symlink-to-dir
> options are specified.

on https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#General-output-formatting