# What does the * with a file name signify?

Tags: ls

[image: what is the meaning of the * as shown in picture]

Can someone tell me the significance of * sign after a file name ?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself and format it as code with the `{}` icon in the editor.

Comment: See [What do the symbols displayed by ls -F mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82357/what-do-the-symbols-displayed-by-ls-f-mean?rq=1) (you probably have `ls` aliased to `ls -F` in your shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is signify that the file is an executable, in other words the file have the right of execution, it's a script or a binary.