# ls -F: where is the official Unix/Linux complete list of the indicator entries types?

Tags: files, filesystems, ls

About `ls -F` in the `man ls` for `-F` does mention about:

```
-F, --classify
  append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

I read the following:

- [What do the symbols displayed by ls -F mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82357/what-do-the-symbols-displayed-by-ls-f-mean)
- [14. How to make ls specifically indicate the type of file in the output](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-ls-command/#-how-to-make-ls-specifically-indicate-the-type-of-file-in-the-output)

Where the list is:

```
@ indicates a symbolic link 
* indicates an executable 
= indicates a socket file 
| indicates a named pipe 
> indicates a door 
/ indicates a directory
```

But, where is the official Unix/Linux complete list of the indicator entries types? of course including their description

Comment: There isn't a "Unix/Linux complete list". The "indicators" are features of `ls`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbols added by `ls -F` are [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) as follows:

> Write a <slash> (`'/'`) immediately after each pathname that is a directory, an <asterisk> (`'*'`) after each that is executable, a <vertical-line> (`'|'`) after each that is a FIFO, and an at-sign (`'@'`) after each that is a symbolic link. For other file types, other symbols may be written.

This is the official specification for POSIX-compliant systems.

The last sentence in the quote above allows implementations to add other symbols for other file types; for GNU `ls`, [the documentation specifies](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html):

> Append a character to each file name indicating the file type. Also, for regular files that are executable, append ‘`*`’. The file type indicators are ‘`/`’ for directories, ‘`@`’ for symbolic links, ‘`|`’ for FIFOs, ‘`=`’ for sockets, ‘`>`’ for doors, and nothing for regular files.

Since each implementation can add its own symbols, there is no official complete list.

Comment: I see - practically each link (about the list of types) complements the other - really wondered why there is no an official and unique complete list.