# Operation not permitted when executing ls in home directory

Tags: ls, macos

I want to list all the files inside `~/Downloads` directory on macOS Catalina. When I execute `ls` I get the following error:

```
ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

`ls` command works in other directories (Desktop, Documents, etc.):

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

```
drwx------   2 subdan  staff    64 Feb 17  2020 Applications
drwx------@  7 subdan  staff   224 Sep 21 20:04 Desktop
drwx------@ 14 subdan  staff   448 Sep 21 18:24 Documents
drwx------@  7 subdan  staff   224 Sep 21 19:54 Downloads
drwx------@ 77 subdan  staff  2464 Sep 21 10:11 Library
drwx------+ 10 subdan  staff   320 Jun 12 17:18 Movies
drwx------+  6 subdan  staff   192 Jun 12 17:18 Music
drwx------+ 15 subdan  staff   480 Jun 12 17:18 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  5 subdan  staff   160 Dec 30  2019 Public
```

Comment: In `~`, run `ls -l`.  You'll probably find the owner of `~/Downloads` is no longer yourself, or it is not owner-readable.

Comment: I've added `ls -l` output.

Comment: What does `@` mean in the `ls -l` output ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catalina has separate controls to limit access to Desktop, Documents and Downloads.

- go to System Preferences
- open "Security & Privacy"
- click on the "Privacy" tab
- in the list on the left select "Files and Folders"
- in list on the right look for "Terminal" (or iTerm if that is what you are  using)
- enable the checkbox next to "Downloads Folder"

Comment: Thanks you, laktak!